# How do I convert any arbitrary .EXE to .DLL, in order to bypass program restrictions?

Tags: windows, restrictions

On a computer that blocks third-party programs, I figured that you could use use PowerShell and C#'s `DllImport()` function to import a native C program as a DLL and run it, and the program would simply appear as part of `powershell.exe` in the Task Manager. Now, for your own C Win32 programs that you have the source code for, turning it into a DLL is as easy as changing the Visual Studio project type from EXE to DLL, and adding `_declspec(dllexport)` before the `main()` function, and compiling it. But how could I convert any arbitrary program, even one that I didn't have the source code of, to a DLL?

Comment: If it were that easy, you could just `DllImport` an arbitrary EXE, instead of only being able to `Assembly.Load` .NET pure MSIL EXEs and DllImport being restricted to DLLs.

Comment: @BenVoigt Can you actually `DllImport` EXEs?

Comment: You can `Assembly.Load` EXEs just like DLLs.  You can use `DllImportAttribute` and pass a filename ending in .exe, but the internal call to `LoadLibraryEx` will fail if that file isn't actually a DLL (historically several Microsoft DLLs have had .exe file extensions).  This should tell you that it isn't just a gratuitous check for a .DLL file extension, but something actually different about the behavior of a PE file depending on whether it is a DLL or not.

Comment: Also, the fact that `LoadLibraryEx` will load not-DLL PE files, such as EXEs, with the `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` flag proves that this isn't something that is easy and was merely overlooked.

Comment: @BenVoigt May you please clarify? I don't quite understand what you mean. I was wondering how I could use `DllImport()` or a similar function to import unmanaged .EXE desktop GUI apps and call their `main()` function to get them to run normally with the usual GUI interface as if you opened the EXE.